# Does the Buckingham PI theorem require base units?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, applications, dimensional-analysis

When implementing the Buckingham PI theorem, it is common to use basis dimensions such as `[MASS, LENGTH, TIME]`, where each is a base SI unit `(kilogram, meter, second)`.

I am attempting a dimensional analysis of a heat transfer system which is represented by basis dimensions `[MASS, LENGTH, TIME, TEMPERATURE]`. However, I have no need to directly access `[TIME]`, and eliminating it would be beneficial; I have a small number of physical dimensions.

Is it valid to utilize the basis dimensions `[POWER, LENGTH, TEMPERATURE]` for my analysis, where `[POWER]` in `(watts)` can be expressed as `LENGTH^2 * MASS * TIME^-3` in the `[MASS, LENGTH, TIME, TEMPERATURE]` system? My concern is that `[POWER]` can be expressed in part by `[LENGTH]`, which is also a dimension in my `[POWER, LENGTH, TEMPERATURE]` system; will this double-dipping on the units interfere with the results?

Comment: What is "Buckingham PI theorem" ? Sure it is absolutely unknown by 99.9% of people... You have to give a reference !

Comment: Its a very well known methodology for dimensional analysis; probably taught to everyone that does more than core math in college. If you don't know what it is, then you probably can't help. Anyways, here is the link if you are interested: [Buckingham PI Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckingham_%CF%80_theorem).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I should have said "unknown in my country" (France) and probably other countries in continental Europe under this name.

Comment: Is there an alternative name for the Buckingham PI theorem?